# Handling accents in R

Tags: r, database, non-ascii-characters

I know that this kind of question was asked before but I still don't know how to solve the problem I got even after choosing the default tex coding to be UTF-8 following these steps: Tools->Global options -> Code.
In my database I need to have in the 3rd column: Ingénierie Cycle Préparatoire.
However, r doesn't accept the accents.
Please help me!

[image]

Comment: How do you fill that data.frame ? Reading a csv ? We need a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), otherwise is difficult to help...

Comment: Not a csv, reading an excel like this:  library(xlsx)
data=read.xlsx(file=file.choose(),sheetIndex = 1)
View(data)

Comment: Set the encoding in the function : `data=read.xlsx(file='test.xlsx',sheetIndex = 1,encoding = 'UTF-8')`

Comment: That works! Thank you very much for your help.